# how to print values of input field into existing form

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, print-css

I have a form available in my hand, also i have build form with same input field in jsp, now i want every inserted values of form to be printed in their respective fields of existing form fields. Please help me.

Comment: did you try Ctl + p or cmd + p and previewing a pdf of the print?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what you mean with 'printed form'? please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please rephrase your question so that it is more understandable.

maybe you are looking for something like this?

or if you are looking at changing the way the inputs look when printed look at this article

https://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint

[Print Stylesheet - Converting inputs to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318204/print-stylesheet-converting-inputs-to-text)